# Backbone.js model: overwriting parse for custom API

Tags: backbone.js

In Backbone.js, I'm working with an API which wraps the response in a `meta` and `data` hash. For example:

```
# GET /api/posts/1
meta: {
  status: 200
},
data: {
  id: 1
  title: 'Hello World'
}

# GET /api/posts
meta: {
  status: 200
},
data: [
  {
    id: 1
    title: 'Hello World'
  },
  { 
    id: 2
    title: 'Hi everyone!'
  }
]
```

My Backbone.js Collection/Models have the following parse function overwritten:

```
# App.Models.Post
... 
parse: function (response) {
   this.meta = response.meta;
   return response.data;
}

# App.Collections.Posts
... 
parse: function (response) {
   this.meta = response.meta;
   return response.data;
}
```

However, when I fetch on the collection `posts = new App.Collections.Posts(); posts.fetch()`, the post attributes are all empty. I.e. `posts.at(0).get('title') = undefined`.

Now, this is fixed when the Model parse is changed to:

```
parse: function (response) {
   return response;
}
```

But this means that `post.fetch()` is broken.
Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried doing a console.log(response) to see what the response object contains?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is that your model's `parse` is getting inconsistent data passed into it when done via model `fetch` vs collection `fetch`. `console.log` the argument to model `parse` to confirm this. This is because the value return by collection's `parse` is just an array of object data and to convert those to models, the collection just delegates to the model's `parse` method. This might fix your issue:

```
//App.Models.Post
parse: function (response) {
    if (response.data) {
        return response.data;
    }
    return response;
}
```

For reference: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/773

Comment: AWESOME!  i've been wondering wtf was happening to my data parsing. thank you.

Comment: i merged this together with another post i found.  try 
`parse : function( response ){
    if( _.isObject(response.data) ){
        return response.data;
    }
    return response;
}`

Comment: Spent few hours figuring out how to display this.collection.models.I added this to my collection. Works.